# Should we have a canonical software question?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

We seem to get many questions like  [Chemical software for solving reactions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/chemical-software-for-solving-reactions) and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5537/application-or-website-for-chemical-reaction-emulation which ask for software that can "solve" chemical reactions. And we have a few other posts on various other types of software.

It may be beneficial to create a single canonical community wiki Q&A for chemistry software for various tasks.

[bobthechemist](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/1573/bobthechemist) has made a good start in drafting the question:

> Possible phrasing for a CW question seeking information about software relevant to Chemistry: Many visitors to Chemistry.SE are looking for software to facilitate their chemistry-related activities. The basic types of software packages available can be obtained through appropriately crafted web searches, so I am interested here in identifying not only the software package but also the area of chemistry it pertains to (simulations, drawing, virtual lab, ...)

Should we do this? (feel free to draft the question and/or answers as an answer to this meta question)

An alternative idea is to have a canonical question that *only* covers reaction-solvers.